# How to handle required relationships in Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

### Local SQL

Locally in my application I have data models **Foo** and **Bar**, each stored in a separate SQL table.

Foo references Bar by its `id`, and it would be an error to have a Foo without its counterpart: Bar.

Sometimes they are shown together, other times only one is shown at a time, and its possible to edit one without it affecting the other.

### Firebase Realtime Database

I am now investigating how I can best integrate it into my application to ensure a smooth sync & backup experience. Everything is pretty much straight forward; **but I cannot wrap my head around how I can ensure that the above mentioned contract stays true.**

There will be cases where Foo is synchronized; and Bar is only synchronized sometime later (consider a simple drop of network connectivity). During this period of time, the realtime database for this particular user would be considered to be in an illegal state. When connectivity returns, both Foo and Bar will eventually be synchronized and the entire thing can continue flowing - but what do I do until then? How can I safeguard against it? Do I need to, or am I looking for the answers in all the wrong places?

**Some ideas that Ive been exploring:**

- Allow Bar to be missing locally. Consider Foo to be in a partial state whenever its bar is missing, e.g. it could be hidden in the UI until its "ready".
- Somehow combine Foo and Bar locally, only save Foo when its Bar is available, etc.
- Nest Bar inside Foo such that theyre always synchronized together. (This seems troublesome, I have a couple of relationships like Foo->Bar in my application and I would have to nest Bar inside all of them if this was the 'correct' way of handling it)

Please enlighten me if you can. Firebase isnt new to me, but synchronizing this kind of complex data with a multitude of relationships, is.

### Additional context

While I cant share the actual Foo & Bar, I have an example which I believe resembles the challenge well.

Consider a chat application where there are messages, rooms and users.

You can post a message to a room, and you can edit a room name and color. A message cannot exist without a user and a room. When looking at it from a sync perspective, user, room and message now has to be synchronized "together" (or at the very least, a message would be invalid if it came through without the others).

Handling this with multi-path updates I would update all 3 everytime a message is posted/edited. Have I understood this correctly? If so, that would mean updating 1+N+N nodes in my own scenario. The N+N nodes wouldnt have any actual updated data, but would be included in the update to ensure all of it is synchronized together.

### Further clarity

First, going back to the root of the problem - Foo references Bar by its id locally. If my application ends up in a state where either exist without the other, it would cause issues pretty much everywhere (this is what Im referring to as an illegal state, it *cannot* happen).

Considering ways to safeguard against it, Ive been recommended to use a multi-path update in firebase (I believe this is similar/identical to fan-out?). Ill try this approach shortly even though Im feeling reserved about it, just to verify whether what Im feeling is just from inexperience.

Im having a very hard time wrapping my head around the fact that if Foo changes locally, it would now also result in a query happening for Bar, such that both can be synchronized together to firebase. It sounds OK for such a simple scenario, however in practice it would mean something along the lines of: you make an edit to X and it gets saved locally, shortly thereafter a sync is happening to firebase, now 100:s of Y and Z are queried as well, and inserted into firebase in the same operation. Y & Z are likely already up to date in firebase at this point, and they havent changed locally.

I dont have much experience with these kinds of scenarios when it comes to firebase, my thinking goes along the lines of it being a huge waste of resources - Im sure firebase does a lot of work locally such that unnecessary synchronization work wont happen for data that hasnt actually changed, but I cant escape the thought that I would still be querying for 100:s and 100:s of complex models locally *a lot*, in cases where it doesnt **seem** necessary (surely another approach must exist where I tackle the problem from another angle?).

Comment: The question is a bit vague and some of the language used isn't clear. For example; Firebase has *transactions* where a write of data must all succeed or else it all fails. So when Foo and Bar are first written, that would be done within a transaction - that guarantees they both exist which would eliminate the possibility that an object is "missing" (whatever missing means). What does 'illegal state' mean? If both Foo and Bar exist in Firebase, and bar is edited while offline, when the app is online, those changes sync and Bar is updated. Perhaps you can provide a more concrete example?

Comment: I added some 'further clarity' to my post - hopefully it makes more sense now. While a transaction would help ensuring that a sync of Foo & Bar succeed or fail together, it would still involve me doing all of those queries (more on that in my post).

Comment: Still pretty vague unfortunately. You're stating *either exist without the other* and with a transactional write, that cannot happen. When foo and bar are first written, it will be done in a write transaction which guarantees they both exist, so having one without the other - *is not possible* -. Also this *Foo references Bar by its id locally.*` is not a concept in Firebase; it's an online first database and referencing something locally vs online is "not something you can do"

Comment: Also, Firebase is NOT a relational database so this *if Foo changes locally, it would now also result in a query happening for Bar* isn't something that can happen. You can query for Foo or change foo but that is NOT related to Bar in any way. e.g. you can update Foo all day long but that has nothing to do with a query for Bar as they are NOT related (because as mentioned, Firebase is not a relational database). Something more concrete may help us understand the quandary but again, Foo and Bar are totally separate pieces of data with no automated relationship.

Comment: The relationships I was referring to are all local (SQL); updating Foo leading to queries for Bar is also local, since Id need to include Bar in my update to firebase Id need to fetch it locally as well. I do cache, but querying for "Bar" is actually something like 10 queries from different tables in my scenario, hence it feeling very ineffective. If theres any other "technique" like fan out, Id love to know; but Ill give that an honest chance to start with.

Comment: Based on that, the question is un-answerable as there is no way for us to know what your SQL queries query for or what the results are. We couldn't even suggest a technique because we don't know the scope of what is being updated locally vs in Firebase. I would suggest just using one database or the other. Supporting two platforms is a LOT of extra work and code and can become unwieldy. In the future please post *code specific* questions as that's what SO is for - what if, how do i type questions get very chatty (as you can see) and rarely have a specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

> There will be cases where Foo is synchronized; and Bar is only synchronized sometime later (consider a simple drop of network connectivity).

If both writes come from the same client, consider [using multi-path updates](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html) to prevent such partial updates.

Comment: Just so that I understand you correctly, doing this is like writing Foo & Bar in one transaction - without explicitly including Bar as a nested value of Foo?

Comment: Yeah. I recommend giving it a try. If you're still getting stuck, I recommend posting a concrete code sample - as it's hard (for me at least) to reason about Foo and Bar without that.

Comment: Ive included some additional context in my question, please have a look! Im struggling a bit when considering how much data would actually move around everytime something seemingly small is changed.

Comment: More words don't help here, as it just leads to the same recommendation. Did you give the API I suggested a try yet? Did it work? Can you show the code for that?

Comment: Im having a hard time accepting the fact that I would be querying almost all local data everytime I wanted to synchronize 1 small piece of it. Ill be back working on this feature early next week, Ill keep you posted on the progress!

Comment: Hey @zoltish: any update here?

Comment: Hey! Nothing to report yet, I just finished my latest launch and can now devote all my time to this though :)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The OP is using SQL to store their data locally and the sync'ing question more relates to that than to using Firebase. *The relationships I was referring to are all local (SQL); updating Foo leading to queries for Bar is also local, since Id need to include Bar in my update to firebase Id need to fetch it locally as well*

Comment: Is the slack channel perhaps a better place to discuss this? Im open to sharing more specific details about my case as long as I can delete it afterwards!

Comment: Ive applied the fan out technique and it works as expected. I ran into the issue Ive tried explaining in my post too though: I basically end up in a race-condition where if Foo arrives before Bar, my queries will fail until Bar is also available. If there is such a thing as fan-in, thats pretty much what Id want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve this, hopefully this can help someone else out there that runs into the same challenge further down the line!

First and foremost, when registering `ChildEventListener` on a `DatabaseReference`; I get one notification with the latest version of the data, and then notifications each time the data changes.

Using that, I filter data by its "version" (basically a timestamp of when it was edited) so that only data that is newer than the latest local version of it is actually processed.

Anytime a `Foo` comes through and its `Bar` counterpart hasnt arrived yet, Ill mark it as a deferred-task that should be retried after the next sync operation is complete - in almost all cases, `Bar` will come through after `Foo` and the task will succeed on its next retry. In some cases a couple of other sync operations will come through before `Bar`, but my retry logic is all local and cheap, so I dont mind that.

If no `Bar` shows up during this lifetime of the application, its not a problem as the latest version of `Foo` will come through the next time the application is started, and the cycle just repeats itself until both `Foo` & `Bar` are available, at which point theyre inserted into my local database.

I dont know if this is the "correct" way to solve it. But using my knowledge, it is the best I could come up with that works, and I dont see any real downsides to it. Feel free to criticize it in the comments, or provide another answer if you think you have a better solution!

Thank you.